# Right way to get Xamarin Forms Previewer working in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm still getting the gray box with XFPageRendererView text slugged in whenever I try and use the Xamarin Forms Previewer.

I'm on the latest stable build of Xamarin and using latest updated Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.

When I check Xamarin bug report there's an old bug about this from last year marked as closed but it's still "open" for me.[image: XFPageRenderView instead of XAML previewing :(]

Hoping it goes without saying that I know I don't "need" the previewer.  But for basic layout and sanity check it would be so much quicker.

Thanks.

Comment: Another note: I discovered today that the iOS preview works - sometimes.  Android never does and shows the XFPageRendererView above.

Answer (score 3):

Last week this was also my problem. i searched the solution in xamarin forums and they said that if you install a mac agent, forms previewer will work. I dont have a mac so never tried it. the solution that worked for me was to install the latest BETA version of xamarin. 
See image on how to install BETA

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this.  I need to stay on Stable but agree that Beta channel works.  Plus 1 :)

Comment: This page doesn't exist in VS 2017.

Answer (score 1):

## keep up to date JDK version

> Check out JDK current version. **Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Java Development Kit**
>
> Install or Update the JDK
>
> Restart Vs studio 2017

Answer (score 0):

After February 20 someday Xamarin's update fixed the problem. Make sure you installed Java SDK 64 bit. Also before opening the XAML file, please build/rebuild the solution couple of times. And try to open/reopen the file couple of times. For details you can check my [blog here](https://foyzulkarim.wordpress.com/2017/02/28/xamarin-forms-previewer/).